# v-text-field of type number, clicking advances multiple times

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, textfield

I'm using a v-text-field element defined with type number. Looks like this:

```
<v-text-field
 :label="$t('enterNumColsLabel')"
 outlined
 v-model="numRows"
 type="number"
 min=0
>
</v-text-field>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Gvh.png)

My understanding is that clicking on the arrows up/down should increase or decrease the value by one. Clicking and holding should increase or decrease the value until let go. Typically this works, however, sometimes clicking will cause the number to increase until you click on something else.

It doesn't happen consistently enough for me to be able to tell what causes it. Has anyone experienced this and know how to prevent it?

Comment: There's no problem with the code. Share a playground where this *"sometimes clicking will cause the number to increase until you click on something else."* happens.

Comment: I was curious so I just played around with it.  Holding left click and then clicking right click causes the value to increase uncontrollably even after you release left click, and continues until you click away.  [codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/xxQKegd?editors=1010). The "hold to increase" isn't a feature of the native input element so much be something internal to the Vuetify component.  It's a bug, and might not even be something they can prevent in this case, but if it's a big enough deal you can [report it on their github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues)